How to change object values just before serialization in Spring Boot?
I have so many "auditable" classes. I am hiding all the audit fields manually for all the objects. I wanted to create a generic implementation so I have created an abstract class for that:
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public abstract class Auditable {
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = CREATED_DATE_COLUMN, columnDefinition = TIMESTAMP_WITH_ZONE)
    private Date createdDate;

    @Column(name = CREATED_BY_COLUMN)
    private String createdBy;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = LAST_UPDATED_DATE_COLUMN, columnDefinition = TIMESTAMP_WITH_ZONE)
    private Date lastUpdatedDate;

    @Column(name = LAST_UPDATED_BY_COLUMN)
    private String lastUpdatedBy;

    public void clear() {
        this.createdDate = null;
        this.createdBy = null;
        this.lastUpdatedDate = null;
        this.lastUpdatedBy = null;
    }
}

I will extend my classes like that:
@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product extends Auditable {

I tried to override serialize method for "Auditable" object type so just before serialization, I can use .clear() function of all the objects that are "Auditable" but it doesn't work(probably I couldn't do it correctly) How can I do that?

Which serialize method do you mean? Also this is a bad idea, as you have @Entity which means it is a manaaged instance, modifying state might end up in the database. What you are better off doing is to create an annotation for JSON (or add @JsonIgnore) which marks that those fields shouldn't be serialized. Final tip don't use @Data with @Entity that is a bad idea (see this blog I wrote on the matter https://deinum.biz/2019-02-13-Lombok-Data-Ojects-Arent-Entities/).

You are making things overly complex. Ditch the clear method, ditch the @JsonInclude and just mark the fields you don't want to serialize with @JsonIgnore.
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public abstract class Auditable {

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = CREATED_DATE_COLUMN, columnDefinition = TIMESTAMP_WITH_ZONE)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Date createdDate;

    @Column(name = CREATED_BY_COLUMN)
    @JsonIgnore
    private String createdBy;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = LAST_UPDATED_DATE_COLUMN, columnDefinition = TIMESTAMP_WITH_ZONE)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Date lastUpdatedDate;

    @Column(name = LAST_UPDATED_BY_COLUMN)
    @JsonIgnore
    private String lastUpdatedBy;

}

Or use @JsonIgnoreProperties on your base class and provide the names of the properties to ignore.
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties("createdDate", "createdBy", "lastUpdatedDate", "lastUpdatedBy")
public abstract class Auditable {

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = CREATED_DATE_COLUMN, columnDefinition = TIMESTAMP_WITH_ZONE)
    private Date createdDate;

    @Column(name = CREATED_BY_COLUMN)
    private String createdBy;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = LAST_UPDATED_DATE_COLUMN, columnDefinition = TIMESTAMP_WITH_ZONE)
    private Date lastUpdatedDate;

    @Column(name = LAST_UPDATED_BY_COLUMN)
    private String lastUpdatedBy;

}

A final option would be to create special DTO's to expose to the outside world, this way you can finely control what you want to expose. Then use something like MapStruct to map from/to DTOs. This solution will also remove the Jackson annotations from your entities. Added benefit is that you keep your entities internal to your application instead of directly exposing them to the outside. Drawback is that you have to do mapping.
public class ProductDTO {
  // Only include fields you want to expose
}

